# What is the standard matrix representation of linear transformation with formula $x_1+x_2+x_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to standard what is the standard representation of this linear transformation:

$$T([x_1,x_2,x_3])=x_1+x_2+x_3$$

What I don't understand is the formula specification, *i.e.*, $$x_1+x_2+x_3$$

In previous exercises the formula is enclosed in vector representation, for example:

$$T([x_1,x_2,x_3])=[x_1 + x_2, x_1-3x_3]$$

Now, how I can interpret the given formula at top?

Thanks in advance for your tips, suggestions, answers!

Comment: This $T$ maps to just one-dimensional space, so there is no need to use commas and surrounding brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case $T$ maps $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ and in the later case $T$ maps $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$

It is to be understood that $x_1+x_2+x_3$ is an element of $\mathbb R$ whereas $[x_1+x_2,x_1-3x_3]$ is an element of $\mathbb R^2$

Now to find the matrix representation of the first case we note since it is a $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ map hence its matrix will be $1\times 3$. And for the elements of the matrix we look into the image of the basis elements of $\mathbb R^3$. We see $(1,0,0) \to 1,(0,1,0) \to 1,(0,0,1) \to 1$ under $T$. Hence the required $1\times 3$ matrix is $[1$   $ 1$   $1]$

Note : Matrix representation depends on what basis we are choosing. In this case I have used standard ordered basis.

Answer (score 2):

Often we implicitly suppose that a vector space of dimesion one over $\Bbb R$ is the same thing as $\Bbb R$.

In your case you might want to write $T([x_1,x_2,x_3])=[x_1+x_2+x_3]$.

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation $T$ can be thought of in terms of the operation of matrix multiplication. In your cases above I would say that the linear transformation $T:\mathbf{x} \to A\mathbf{x}$ where
\begin{align}A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

in the first case you mention and in the second case,

\begin{align}A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 1 & 0 \\
1  & 0 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

I have here assumed $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a column vector.